# Save large quantity variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have in php script large quantity variables. How is optimality, save this data in  individual variables

```
$a = "aaa";
$b = "bbb";
$c = "ccc";
```

or in associative array?

```
$mas = array("a"=>"aaa","b"=>"bbb","c"=>"ccc");
```

which method is better? or no difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

It's better to make an array for variables within the same context.
Example:

```
  $config = array();
```

You can store all your config variables into an array. Of course other variables needed for the execution of your script shouldn't be there.